# How to create multiple functions for running totals from a text file in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, cumulative-sum

After reading and populating the array of structures from the text file, the program should:

1. Use a function to output the
   data about the train.
2. Use a function to calculate and report the total number of cars in the train.
3. Use a function to calculate and report the total amount of horsepower the train requires.
4. Use a function to calculate and report the total
   length of the train and
5. Assuming that a locomotive produces 1000 horsepower, calculate and report the number of locomotives needed to pull the train (round up). The thing is I've never done this before and I can't even figure out where to start from. Use of strsub() is mandatory even though sscanf() would make everything much easier.

I've tried trying to pass the `train[] data` type and create a loop for a running total of `train[i].amount` but obviously I'm doing something wrong.

From traindata.txt

```
Boxcar    D 44000 55 16 45
Hopper    B 23000 62 18 33
Tanker    G 15000 45 30 12
Autocar   A 30000 37 23 6
Livestock L 56500 50 18 19
Coalcar   C 49300 53 22 100
Flatcar   F 18000 66 15 25
```

From train.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 100
FILE *fpIn;

typedef struct {
    char name[10];
    char type;
    float weight;
    int length;
    int power;
    int amount;
}data;

void strsub(char buf[], char sub[], int start, int end);
int readFile();
int numOfCars(data *, int);
int horsePower(data *, int);
int trainLen(data *, int);
int engNeed(int);

// Substring extractor function from book
void strsub(char buf[], char sub[], int start, int end){
    int i, j;

    for (j = 0, i = start; i <= end ; i++, j++){
        sub[j] = buf[i];
    }
    sub[j] = '\0';
}

// Prints out file
void outFile(data* train) {
    printf(" Name: %s ", train->name);
    printf(" Type: %c ", train->type);
    printf(" Weight: %.2f ", train->weight);
    printf(" Length: %d ", train->length);
    printf(" Horsepower: %d ", train->power);
    printf(" Number in Train: %d ", train->amount);

}

// Reads file
int readFile(){
    int count = 0;
    data train[MAX];

    // Opens file
    if(!(fpIn = fopen("traindata.txt", "r"))){
        printf("Error. File can not be opened. \n");
    }

    // Reads each line of text in file
    while (!feof(fpIn)){
        char buf[MAX+2];
        char weightbuf[7];
        char lengthbuf[4];
        char powerbuf[4];
        char amountbuf[6];

        fgets(buf, MAX, fpIn);
        strsub(buf, train[count].name, 0, 8);
        train[count].type = buf[10];
        strsub(buf, weightbuf, 11, 16);
        strsub(buf, lengthbuf, 17, 19);
        strsub(buf, powerbuf, 20, 22);
        strsub(buf, amountbuf, 23, 26);
        train[count].weight = atof(weightbuf);
        train[count].length = atoi(lengthbuf);
        train[count].amount = atoi(amountbuf);
        train[count].power = atoi(powerbuf);
        ++count;

        // where to make those additions
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
        data* trains = &train[i];
        outFile(trains);
    }
}

int numOfCars(data train[],int len){
    int i,total_cars=0;

    for(i=0;i<len;++i){
        total_cars+=train[i].amount;
    }
    return total_cars;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    data train[20];
    printf("This table shows the current Train Cars\n");
    printf("---------------------------------------\n\n");

    int len = readFile();
    printf("\n\nThere are %d Cars in the train.\n", numOfCars(train,len));

    return 0;
}
```

### This table shows the current Train Cars

```
Name: Boxcar     Type: D  Weight: 44000.00  Length: 55  Horsepower: 16  Number in Train: 45 
Name: Hopper     Type: B  Weight: 23000.00  Length: 62  Horsepower: 18  Number in Train: 33 
Name: Tanker     Type: G  Weight: 15000.00  Length: 45  Horsepower: 30  Number in Train: 12  
Name: Autocar    Type: A  Weight: 30000.00  Length: 37  Horsepower: 23  Number in Train: 6  
Name: Livestock  Type: L  Weight: 56500.00  Length: 50  Horsepower: 18  Number in Train: 19  
Name: Coalcar    Type: C  Weight: 49300.00  Length: 53  Horsepower: 22  Number in Train: 100  
Name: Flatcar    Type: F  Weight: 18000.00  Length: 66  Horsepower: 15  Number in Train: 25 

There are 240 Cars in the train.
The total length of the train is 13183
Total horsepower needed to pull train is 4729
The number of engines need to pull the train is 5
```

Comment: Hasn't that been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218440/how-to-read-and-data-from-text-file-to-array-structure-in-c-programming

Comment: @Jabberwocky kind of, that was part 1 but I already figured that out. This question is not how to read the text file but how to make calculation using the strings from that file.

Comment: Seems to me that `readFile` puts the data read into a **local** variable `train`. In `main` you have another local variable named `train`. These are two different variables. Changing one doesn't change the other. In other words - the data you read from the files never makes it into `main`

Comment: But... The printed table shows correct calculation for the number of cars - strange. And where does the rest of the table come from? I don't see hte code that prints the last 3 lines.

Comment: Also... I don't see the code where you try to calculate the total amount. Sure you have posted the correct code?

Comment: @4386427 Yeah for some reason ```readFile``` doesnt work with ```train``` as a global variable but that's something I may have to work on because I need to pass that data to the other functions.

Comment: @ThelmaEmeri No - please don't use a global variable... See the answer I just posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @4386427, this was the final piece of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 100
FILE *fpIn;

typedef struct {
    char name[10];
    char type;
    float weight;
    int length;
    int power;
    int amount;
}data;

void strsub(char buf[], char sub[], int start, int end);
int readFile(data train[]);
void outFile(data train[]);
int numOfCars(data train[], int num);
int horsePower(data train[], int num);
int trainLen(data train[], int num);

// Substring extractor function from book
void strsub(char buf[], char sub[], int start, int end){
    int i, j;

    for (j = 0, i = start; i <= end ; i++, j++){
        sub[j] = buf[i];
    }
    sub[j] = '\0';
}

// Prints out file
void outFile(data train[]) {
    printf(" Name: %s ", train->name);
    printf(" Type: %c ", train->type);
    printf(" Weight: %.2f ", train->weight);
    printf(" Length: %d ", train->length);
    printf(" Horsepower: %d ", train->power);
    printf(" Number in Train: %d ", train->amount);

}

// Reads file
int readFile(data train[]){
    int count = 0;

    // Opens file
    if(!(fpIn = fopen("traindata.txt", "r"))){
        printf("Error. File can not be opened. \n");
    }

    // Reads each line of text in file
    while (!feof(fpIn)){
        char buf[MAX+2];
        char weightbuf[7];
        char lengthbuf[4];
        char powerbuf[4];
        char amountbuf[6];

        fgets(buf, MAX, fpIn);
        strsub(buf, train[count].name, 0, 8);
        train[count].type = buf[10];
        strsub(buf, weightbuf, 11, 16);
        strsub(buf, lengthbuf, 17, 19);
        strsub(buf, powerbuf, 20, 22);
        strsub(buf, amountbuf, 23, 26);
        train[count].weight = atof(weightbuf);
        train[count].length = atoi(lengthbuf);
        train[count].amount = atoi(amountbuf);
        train[count].power  = atoi(powerbuf);
        ++count;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
        data* trains = &train[i];
        outFile(trains);
    }

    numOfCars(train, count);
    trainLen(train, count);
    horsePower(train, count);

    return 0;
}

int numOfCars(data train[], int num){
    int i, totalCars = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
        totalCars += train[i].amount;

    printf("\n\nThere are %d Cars in the Train.", totalCars);
    return totalCars;
}

int trainLen(data train[], int num){
    int i, totalLen = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
        totalLen += (train[i].length * train[i].amount);

    printf("\nThe total length of the train is: %d", totalLen);
    return totalLen;
}

int horsePower(data train[], int num){
    int i, totalHp = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        totalHp += (train[i].amount * train[i].power);

    printf("\nThe total horsepower need for this train is: %d", totalHp);

    int engNeed = totalHp/1000;
    if (totalHp % 1000 != 0)
        engNeed = engNeed+1;

    printf("\n%d number of engines are needed to pull the train.", engNeed);

    return totalHp, engNeed;
}

int main() {
    data train[MAX];

    printf("This table shows the current Train Cars\n");
    printf("---------------------------------------\n\n");

    readFile(train);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The big problem is here:

```
int readFile(){
    int count = 0;
    data train[MAX];  // Local value used for storing data read from the file
```

When you read from the file and store the data into a **local** variable, those data will be lost when the function returns. In other words - your `train` variable inside the `main` function will not hold the data read from the file.

To fix that you need to pass the `train` variable from `main` to the function. Like:

```
int readFile(data train[]){
    int count = 0;
    // delete this line !! data train[MAX];
    ...
```

and in `main` call it like:

```
int len = readFile(train);
```

Notice that it is a good idea also to pass the maximum number of elements that the array can hold. So consider:

```
int readFile(data train[], int max){
    int count = 0;
```

and call it like:

```
data train[20];
int len = readFile(train, sizeof(train) / sizeof(data));
```

or alternatively:

```
data train[MAX];
int len = readFile(train, MAX);
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment, it's really headed me to the right direction. I'm guessing passing ```data train[]``` to the functions' parameters make it easier to make calculations from the file. However i'm not sure how to pass the ```#define MAX 100```. Is there a correct syntax for that?